# Software to Pose and Export FBX Character

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, software, cad

I am a beginner and looking for software to easily pose a 3D character, which I currently have in an FBX file, and export the pose to an OBJ file.

For example, I could move the character's arm upward, then export that as an OBJ and print it.

Every software I know of either can not pose FBX characters (such as Fusion360) or can not export poses (such as Blender). How can I do this easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pose it in Blender you can export it and print it with the pose. It's very simple, you just export as a STL file and then print.